# PC with Static IP all of a sudden not working on Network Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, ip, static-ip

I have a PC that was working with a static IP for months. All of a sudden today it stopped showing on the network and when I enter `ipconfig` in cmd it shows a different IP address than what is assigned statically. All other computers on the network are working as expected.

Example: IPv4 is configured as:

```
192.168.0.130  
255.255.255.0  
192.168.0.1
```

What is displayed in cmd with ipconfig:

```
169.254.142.33  
255.255.255.0  
192.168.0.1
```

If I set the IPv4 to Dynamic and do `netsh winsock reset` followed with `ipconfig /release` and `renew` after restart it works fine.

Any ideas on what caused this or how to resolve?

Comment: 169.254.x.x is a self-assigned IP address - meaning it can't find its DHCP server, or that server isn't giving out an address when asked..

Comment: @Tetsujin gotcha. How can I resolve this though? And how could this have happened to only this PC out of nowhere?

Comment: Where does 192.168.0.130 come from initially? Is it a fixed assignment on DHCP or was it manually set on the local PC? If it came from a DHCP server, check the standard pool doesn't include that address, or that it's been given to another machine.

Comment: 192.168.0.130 is the static address I assigned for IPv4. I have 10 computers that start from 192.168.0.120 - 130 and all work good except for the one on .130.

Comment: 'Assigned' where? & did you check the other things i asked?

Comment: Sorry, assigned through adapter options> Ethernet> IPv4. Manually set on the local PC. All items on the local network are static IP addresses manually assigned. No other item on the network has that IP address. 

If I change the pc over to Obtain an IP address automatically it works fine.

Comment: Then I'm stumped - if you manually set an IP address at the local machine, it should never even look for a DHCP server, so it should never fail & end up with a 169.254 address. Something really doesn't add up somewhere. [Smartest, btw, is to use DHCP even for static addresses, fix them at your gateway, keep the regular pool out of its way & allow everything to be handled centrally.]

Comment: I've had this issue before, for me it was after I had been messing around with the drivers for my wireless adapter, once I uninstalled and re-installed the wireless adapter I had no issues

Answer (score 0):

After countless reboots and changes, the solution ended up being turning on DHCP, which successfully received a new IP, and then turning static IP back on.

Seems like a weird bug where even though an static IP is set on the config dialog, windows is still searching *somewhere* for a DHCP to get an IP from.

Hopefully saves someone 30 mins of rebooting stuff (:

Answer (score 0):

Having tried many suggestions I found here and elsewhere on the internet, what worked for me was connecting a USB ethernet adaptor.

I configured it with a static IP address and made sure I could ping another system. Then I moved the ethernet cable back to the built-in ethernet port. Lo and behold! Its static IP address is working again!